# Copying a Website Template to AWS LightSail Joomal Stack

Tags: templates, configuration, installation, joomla3.0, bitnami

I have purchased a Joomla website template (including all content and images) from www.templatemonster.com/. When I was originally developing the website on my local machine using MAMP I created a folder under the HTDOCS parent directory and access the website by typing 'localhost\folder name'.

I have attempted to copy the files to the '/opt/bitnami/apps/folder name' assuming that this would be the correct method given that /opt/bitnami/apps/ contains the folders and files for the phpmyadmin dashboard, however this doesn't seem to work.

I followed the instructions as per https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/joomla/#how-to-install-multiple-joomla-applications-in-the-same-instance, but this doesn't work because the conf directory doesn't exist within the template files.  I assume this is because the Bitnami Stack includes the conf and htdocs directories under the Joomla parent by default, whereas in MAMPS the htpdocs directory would be the parent to the directories containing the content and so forth.

Is there something I am missing from this process?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you the following:

- First make a backup of `/opt/bitnami/apps/joomla`
- Once the backup is done. Copy the template to `/opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/htdocs`
- If it is a template with database contents you will also need to migrate the template database to mysql. The included phpmyadmin can be helpful.
- You will probably have to modify the configuration files in case they are overwritten. Use the previously backed up folder for reference.